# Write a triangle in the space in parametric form

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I want to write the triangle of vertices $A(0,0,0)$, $B(1,1,1)$ and $C(0,0,2)$ in parametric form.

I did the following:

I know that the plane that contains these 3 points is

$x=y$

so a parametric equation of the plane is $(x,y,z)=(u,u,v)$ with $u,v\in\mathbb{R}$.

Following my intuition, the triangle can be wrote parametrically as follows:

$(x,y,z)=(u,u,v)$ with $0\leq u\leq 1$ and $u\leq v\leq 2-u$.

I am right? What I finally want is to calculate an integral over the triangle, and for that I need this, to have the right limit for the integral.

Comment: You mean $\le 2-u$, of course.

Comment: Yes @TedShifrin, do you think that it is ok?

Comment: Yes, it’s fine! Draw the 2-D picture in the $uv$-plane, to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Any point $P$ on the perimeter or the interior of $\triangle ABC$  can be written as a linear combination of the coordinates of $A,B,C$ (Barycentric coordinates)

$P = t A + s B + (1 - t - s) C $

where $0 \le t \le 1$ , and $ 0 \le s \le  1 - t $.

Using the coordinates for $A, B, C$ in the problem, we have

$P = t (0, 0, 0) + s (1, 1, 1) + (1 - t - s) (0, 0, 2) = (s , s, 2 - 2 t - s ) $

Comparing this to the form you got which is $(u, u, v)$ we get $u = s$ and $v = 2 - 2 t - s $

Imposing $ 0 \le s \le 1 $ and $ 0 \le t \le 1 - s $ leads to

$ 0 \le u \le 1 $ and $ 0 \le  \frac{1}{2} (2 - u - v) \le 1 - u $, which simplifies to

$ 0 \le 2 - u - v \le 2 - 2 u $

Multiplying by $(-1)$

$ 0 \ge u + v - 2 \ge 2 u - 2 $

Adding $2 - u$ throughout

$ 2 - u \ge v \ge u $

which is the same as $ u \le v \le 2 - u $  , the inequality that you derived in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will do the job:

$r:[0, 1]\times [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
$$
\begin{aligned}
r(u,v)
&= (Au + B(1-u))v + C(1-v)\\
&= Auv + B(1-u)v + C(1-v)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are the position vectors of the points.

The underlying idea: First, find the point on the segment $AB$, $P = Au + B(1-u)$, and find a point on the segment $P$ and $C$, $Pv + C(1-v)$. Thank you.

Comment: This gives special treatment to the point $C$, in the sense that it corresponds to an infinite number of $(u,v)$ values. If you wanted, you could give $A$ or $B$ this same special treatment, instead. You might find the subsequent algebra easier if you treat $A = (0,0,0)$ as the special vertex.